# Making a persistent SSO with OAuth2 Client and ADFS 3.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, jwt, adfs

I have a hybrid(Ionic) mobile app is registered as an OAuth2 client with ADFS3.0.
Now, i am doing Authorization Code Grant Method of OAuth2 as it is the only method supported by ADFS3.0. I am successfully getting the access token, and staying in the session.
But, after 1 hour, when the access token expires, and ADFS asks me to enter my credentials again. How to make this a persistent SSO.

I am using Cordova Inappbrowser to call the ADFS Url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you got the original tokens, you should have received a refresh token as well.

Then use something like:

POST xxx/token

- grant_type=refresh_token
- client_id=xxx
- client_secret=yyy
- refresh_token=token

Comment: So, will this work even if i close my app and restart it after the access token expires

Comment: The refresh token also expires after a while. If you use one of the Microsoft stacks e.g. ADAL or OWIN, the refresh is done for you.

Comment: we don't use ADAL or OWIN. Just to clarify, First store the access token in localstorage. Then, every time an user opens the app i have to check if the access token is valid, if not use the refresh token to get a new access token. With that will come another refresh token. And this process will continue, Am i right?

Comment: Yup. Just to note storing storing tokens needs to be secure!

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Just one last thing, how to secure the storage of tokens.

@nzpcmad